# Disable VSTS build trigger when creating tag

Tags: build, azure-devops, yaml

I have a YAML build definition in VSTS working fine for some times.
I recently started to tag my repo from my release definition using [this task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jabbera.git-tag-on-release-task).

It is working pretty fine, except that each time this task add a new lightweight tag to my repo, it also trigger my CI on that tag. The branch associated to the build is `refs/tags/mytag`.

I tried to prevent that behavior by adding trigger branch filter in my YAML definition:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - release
    exclude:
    - refs/tags/*
```

But my build is still being triggered.

Any idea about how to prevent triggering a build definition when creating a new tag?

---

**Note**

I also tried by creating a Tag myself from the VSTS portal (which in that case is NOT a lightweight tag). The build is still being triggered, but in a different way because it is failing with error message `Expected a Commit, but objectId f768714f0bac926164dea5b77e696da7a73db426 resolved to a Tag`.

Also the version string is not properly computed in that case and result in a simple `int` instead of my formatted version string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, there has no options to specify tags include/exclude to trigger the CI build.

And there has the user vice [Trigger build when pushing tag to git](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/13326927-trigger-build-when-pushing-tag-to-git) which suggest the feature to specify tags in CI build, you can vote and follow up.

The workaround for now is **override YAML Continuous Integration trigger from Triggers Tab**:

In your YAML build definition -> Triggers Tab -> Override YAML Continuous Integration trigger from here -> Include the branches you want to trigger the branch (`master` and `release` branches for your situation) -> Save build definition.

[image]

Now only commits are pushed to `master` or `release` branch will trigger the CI build, and tags creation will not trigger CI build.

Comment: I tested it, it worked, thanks. Just to clarify, triggering a build from a tag did work properly in my case...